# How to get the correct "this" element when using jQuery on() with two selectors

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-on

Consider the following code:

```
$('#main').on('click', 'a', function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

`$(this)` will always correspond to the `#main` element and not to the `<a>` clicked. How can I get the `<a>` that was clicked?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Sorry it seems like you guys are correct: http://jsfiddle.net/R2rJU/1/

My problem was that I saved the second selector's results to a variable, making it unusable as a selector.

Comment: No, `this` will be set to refer to the `<a>` element that was clicked. Your premise is incorrect.

Comment: [Here is a jsbin to demonstrate.](http://jsbin.com/obulip/1)

Comment: Probably a bubbling issue imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you seem to be mistaking something. `this` will always refer to the DOM element being clicked inside the click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the click handler of `<a>` tag. so you are doing correct

if you want to use explicitly then you can use `event.target` [Event.Target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

```
 $("#main").html("clicked: " + event.target.nodeName);
```

Comment: According to the [jQuery .on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler), _"`this` may not be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant element"_ — Meaning that in my example if a `<span>` element within a `<a>` element is clicked, then `this` will be the `<a>` element while the `event.target` will be the `<span>` element.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#main').on('click', 'a', function() {
    console.log($('#main :selected').text());
});
```